# Prove by using step functions: $\int_{-b}^{b}\sin(x)\ dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

The Assignment:

> Let $b > 0$. Prove by using step functions: $$\int_{-b}^{b}\sin(x)\ dx = 0$$

The claim itself is obvious, but I have no idea how to prove it with step functions. My idea was to show that $$\int_{-b}^{0}\sin(x)\ dx = \int_{0}^{b}\sin(x)\ dx$$
Naturally (after similar tasks), I tried to approximate the integral with
$$\int_{0}^{b}\sin(x)\ dx = \frac{b}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}\sin\left(\frac{b}{n}i\right)$$ but I know neither if my approach is even remotely correct nor how to go on from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is kind of a silly assignment.  $\sin{}$ is an odd function.

Comment: I agree. No idea what I'm supposed to do because every approach will end with a triviality.

Comment: Fourier series of sgn function in terms of step function and go from there? I haven't worked it out yet, but I think it would work.

Comment: @SimonMeans Thanks for your help, but I have not been introduced to Fourier series as of now.

Comment: Then i'm at a loss. This seems like a very weird problem to assign. May I ask what type of class this is for?

Comment: @SimonMeans "Analysis II", if that means anything to you.

Answer (score 1):

This might call for an application of Darboux's theorem, that it suffices you take a sequence of partitions with mesh going to zero and compute say $\lim U(f,P_n)$. Of course, you can choose partitions $P_n$ so that each $U(f,P_n)=0$ by exploiting oddness, so the integral $=\lim U(f,P_n)=0$.